# Why aren't all my widgets showing when I make a new window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a tkinter text editor that has a window with a text widget, a top menu, 2 scrollbars, and a right click menu. In the top menu, I've made an option to make a new window. When I press "new window", it makes a new window, however, it doesn't have all the widgets. While it has the text widget and scrollbars, it does not have the top menu. I am using python 3.8.2. This is my code for the window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import font
...
class Window(tk.Tk):
    current_open_file = "New File"
    current_open_doc = "Untitled Document"
    modified = False
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.font_size = 10
        txt = tk.Text(self, undo=True, wrap=tk.NONE)
        txtFont = font.Font(family='Arial', size=self.font_size)
        txt.configure(font=txtFont)
        self.title('Text Editor')
        self.grid_propagate(0)
        self.geometry("600x400")
        self.iconbitmap(r'./assets/my_logo.ico')

        yscroller = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=txt.yview)
        txt['yscrollcommand'] = yscroller.set
        yscroller.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        xscroller = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=txt.xview)
        txt['xscrollcommand'] = xscroller.set
        xscroller.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        txt.bind("<Control-s>", lambda x: TopMenu.saveFile(self, txt, self))
        txt.bind("<Control-S>", lambda x: TopMenu.saveFile(self, txt, self))
        txt.bind("<Control-Shift-s>", lambda x: TopMenu.saveFileAs(self, txt, self))
        txt.bind("<Control-Shift-S>", lambda x: TopMenu.saveFileAs(self, txt, self))
        txt.bind("<Control-o>", lambda x: TopMenu.openFile(self, txt, self))
        txt.bind("<Control-O>", lambda x: TopMenu.openFile(self, txt, self))
        txt.bind('<Key>', self.modification)
        txt.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, side=tk.LEFT)

        menu = TopMenu(self, txt)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        self.clickmenu = RightClickMenu(self, txt, tearoff=False)
```

The "Topmenu" class is for the top menu and inherits from tk.Menu. The "RightClickMenu" class is for the right click menu and also inherits from tk.Menu. This is my code for running the windows.

```
windows = [Window()]
for window in windows:
    window.mainloop()
```

To open a new window, I do this, `windows.append(Window())`. Also, I have recently seen comments about it not being good practice to have multiple Tk() widgets. I believe that this may be somewhat related to this problem. Here a few pictures of my screen.

[image: A picture of the initial window]

[image: A picture of a new window]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing `for window in windows: window.mainloop()`? You should call `mainloop()` exactly once, and only have a single root window. If you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`, that's definitely part of the problem.

Comment: Okay sure. I see that there is the option of Toplevel(), but I don't want to use it due to the fact that when I close the main window, then the Toplevels will close. Is there a way to work around this? Thanks.

Comment: Hide the root window and make all of the user-visible facing windows Toplevels. When the only remaining Toplevel is destroyed, have it kill the root window.

Comment: Thanks you. I will do that and keep this information in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating multiple instances of `Tk`, and you are calling `mainloop()` for each one, that's the problem. Tkinter is single threaded, it can only service a single event loop at a time.

When you call mainloop, it literally is a loop in the current thread that is waiting for events. If you call mainloop a second time in the same thread, the first one will stop functioning until the second one finishes. If you call it a third time, the second one will stop functioning. And so on.